# AutoMapper comma delimited string

Tags: automapper

I have a comma delimited string and want to map it to an object. Is this possible to do with automapper?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample code? How the target object and your string list look like?

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing too many details, it seems to me there are two ways to accomplish this, given the following DTO that we want to populate:

```cs
public class DTO 
{
    public string FirstName { get;set; }
    public string LastName { get;set; }
}
```

and sample input:

```cs
string input = "Andrew,Whitaker";
```

1. Write a custom type converter (recommended):

   ```cs
   public class CommaDelimitedStringConverter : TypeConverter<string, DTO>
   {
       protected override DTO ConvertCore(string source)
       {
           string[] tokens = source.Split(',');

           DTO result = null;

           if (tokens.Length == 2) 
           {        
               result = new DTO();
               result.FirstName = tokens[0];
               result.LastName = tokens[1];
           }
           return result;
       }
   }

   Mapper.CreateMap<string, DTO>()
       .ConvertUsing<CommaDelimitedStringConverter>();
   ```
2. Map each property one-off (not recommended unless this is quick and dirty):

   ```cs
   Mapper.CreateMap<string, DTO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Split(',')[0]))
       .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Split(',')[1]));
   ```